# Print matching header columns from different files

Tags: shell, awk

I have a couple of files.

```
cat << EOF > file1.csv
val 1, val 2, val 5, val 6
34,12,23,54
22,32,22,43
12,32,11,31
32,32,44,22
32,34,23,45
EOF

cat << EOF > file2.csv
val 5, val 2, val 3, val 4, val 7
4,82,13,4,33
2,22,42,3,23
1,42,51,1,67
33,42,84,2,43
42,44,93,5,56
23,42,32,32,34
32,43,22,11,2
EOF
```

I would like to print columns under "val 2" and "val 5" from the two files and write them in a separate file. Also, there are 5 rows in file1.csv while 7 rows in file2.csv, so the missing values will be printed as"?".

My script:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=", "; OFS=" " }
     NR==FNR {
        if (FNR > 1) {
            val2[FNR-1] = $2
            val5[FNR-1] = $3
        }
        next
     }
     {
        if (FNR > 1) {
            val2[FNR-1] = val2[FNR-1] " " $2
            val5[FNR-1] = val5[FNR-1] " " $5
        }
     }
     END {
        print "val 2"
        for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
            if (i <= length(val2)) {
                print val2[i]
            } else {
                print "?"
            }
        }
        print ""
        print "val 5"
        for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
            if (i <= length(val5)) {
                print val5[i]
            } else {
                print "?"
            }
        }
     }' file1.csv file2.csv
```

This is printing something, but they are not correct.

Output will be like

```
cat << EOF > output_val_2.txt
12 82
32 22
32 42
32 42
34 44
?  42
?  43
EOF

cat << EOF > output_val_5.txt
23 4
22 2
11 21
44 33
23 42
?  23
?  32
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a situation where the `join` command is used.

### output.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

header="$1"
file1="$2"
file2="$3"

# Determine row number from header string
rownum () {
  head -1 "$2" \
    | sed -e 's/,\s*/\n/g' \
    | awk -v FS='\t' -v c="$1" '$1 == c { print NR + 1; exit; }'
}

join -e'?' -a1 -a2 \
  -o "1.$(rownum "$header" "$file1"),2.$(rownum "$header" "$file2")" \
  <(nl "$file1" | column -ts,) \
  <(nl "$file2" | column -ts,) \
  | tail -n +2 \
  | column -t
```

```
% ./output.sh 'val 2' file1.csv file2.csv
12  82
32  22
32  42
32  42
34  44
?   42
?   43
```

```
% ./output.sh 'val 5' file1.csv file2.csv
23  4
22  2
11  1
44  33
23  42
?   23
?   32
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk and more variables than necessary and lengthy, meaningful variable names to make the code easiest to understand:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = ", *"
    numTags = split(tags,tagNr2tag)
    for ( tagNr in tagNr2tag ) {
        tag = tagNr2tag[tagNr]
        tag2tagNr[tag] = tagNr
    }
}
FNR==1 {
    rowNr = 1
    colNr = ++numCols
    for ( tagNr in tagNr2tag ) {
        idx = tagNr RS rowNr RS colNr
        vals[idx] = FILENAME
    }

    delete tagNr2fldNr
    for ( fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++ ) {
        tag = $fldNr
        if ( tag in tag2tagNr ) {
            tagNr = tag2tagNr[tag]
            tagNr2fldNr[tagNr] = fldNr
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    ++rowNr
    numRows = ( rowNr > numRows ? rowNr : numRows )
    for ( tagNr in tagNr2fldNr ) {
        fldNr = tagNr2fldNr[tagNr]
        val = $fldNr
        idx = tagNr RS rowNr RS colNr
        vals[idx] = val
    }
}
END {
    for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
        close(out)
        out = "output_" tagNr2tag[tagNr] ".txt"
        gsub(/ +/,"_",out)
        for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
            for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
                idx = tagNr RS rowNr RS colNr
                val = ( idx in vals ? vals[idx] : "?" )
                printf "%s%s", val, ( colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS ) > out
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v tags='val 2,val 5' -f tst.awk file1.csv file2.csv
```

```
$ head output_*.txt
==> output_val_2.txt <==
file1.csv file2.csv
12 82
32 22
32 42
32 42
34 44
? 42
? 43

==> output_val_5.txt <==
file1.csv file2.csv
23 4
22 2
11 1
44 33
23 42
? 23
? 32
```

If you don't want the column header line containing the input file names then just start the output loop `for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ )` at `rowNr=2` instead of `rowNr=1`.

The above will work for any number of input files and any number of columns you want to print from them and for files that don't have some of the target columns and will output the columns in the same order as you provide the file name arguments, e.g.:

```
$ cp file1.csv file3.csv
```

```
$ awk -v tags='val 5,val 4,val 1' -f tst.awk file2.csv file3.csv file1.csv
```

```
$ head output_*
==> output_val_1.txt <==
file2.csv file3.csv file1.csv
? 34 34
? 22 22
? 12 12
? 32 32
? 32 32
? ? ?
? ? ?

==> output_val_4.txt <==
file2.csv file3.csv file1.csv
4 ? ?
3 ? ?
1 ? ?
2 ? ?
5 ? ?
32 ? ?
11 ? ?

==> output_val_5.txt <==
file2.csv file3.csv file1.csv
4 23 23
2 22 22
1 11 11
33 44 44
42 23 23
23 ? ?
32 ? ?
```